# Can I Run virtual box inside Tails

Tags: virtualbox, dpkg, tails-os

I have a TailsOS Related Question: Can I run a virtual box inside tails? I would like to use VirtualBox to run some emulators on it.  I tried to google it but it's always talking about tails inside a VM which is not what I am looking for.

output of  `cat /etc/*-release`

is

> ```
> TAILS_PRODUCT_NAME="Tails"
> TAILS_VERSION_ID="3.2"
> ```

so i went for the deb9 stretch you recomendet as i try to install it prompts

```
sudo dpkg -i '/home/amnesia/Persistent/virtualbox-5.1_5.1.28-117968~Ubuntu~xenial_amd64.deb' 
[sudo] password for amnesia: 
(Reading database ... 137687 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../virtualbox-5.1_5.1.28-117968~Ubuntu~xenial_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking virtualbox-5.1 (5.1.28-117968~Ubuntu~xenial) over (5.1.28-117968~Ubuntu~xenial) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualbox-5.1:
 virtualbox-5.1 depends on libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4); however:
  Package libpng12-0 is not installed.
 virtualbox-5.1 depends on libqt5opengl5 (>= 5.0.2) | libqt5opengl5-gles (>= 5.0.2); however:
  Package libqt5opengl5 is not installed.
  Package libqt5opengl5-gles is not installed.
 virtualbox-5.1 depends on libqt5x11extras5 (>= 5.1.0); however:
  Package libqt5x11extras5 is not installed.
 virtualbox-5.1 depends on libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0); however:
  Package libssl1.0.0 is not installed.
 virtualbox-5.1 depends on libvpx3 (>= 1.5.0); however:
  Package libvpx3 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-5.1 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for systemd (232-25+deb9u1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.8-1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-9) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1.0tails1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-5.1
```

Comment: Did that fix it? You usually have to run sudo apt-get update and then sudo apt-get -f install after using dpkg to manually install stuff because apt-get normally runs dpkg for you and normally handles all of the dependencies so that this doesn't happen when installing stuff from the official repositories. Also, I actually prefer to use gdebi instead of dpkg because gdebi will take care of all of your dependencies automatically. Although, tails used to come with synaptic pre installed which also works well. More info: https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkgtools.en.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able to do this. However, because this is tails, you will have to re-install virtualbox each time you boot tails because tails is not persistent.

You should use the ["Debian-based linux distributions"](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) instructions.

And run the following command in a terminal to show which version of Debian you are using on tails so that you will know which version of Virtualbox to download:

```
cat /etc/*-release
```

Once you know which version of Debian (probably Debian 9 "stretch") that tails is using, download the corresponding version of Virtualbox from the [page linked here.](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads)

---

To fix the dependency issue, please run the following commands in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Please post any errors, thanks!

Comment: output of  `cat /etc/*-release` is                   TAILS_PRODUCT_NAME="Tails"
TAILS_VERSION_ID="3.2"  so i went for the deb9 stretch you recomendet

Comment: seems there are some packages not installed. is there any way i can keep them in persistant storage and write a sript so they install everytime i launch the script?

Comment: @leila Yes, however, you should ask this as another question and also I will update the answer to fix the current issue.

Comment: @leila Also, there is some information on persistence at the following link, although, I am sure there are some questions on the topic already answered here on unix.SE and if not, I'm sure there are users here that are more familiar with the topic than I am especially since it has been a while since the last time I used tails :) https://tails.boum.org/contribute/design/persistence/

Comment: @leila Additionally, I updated the answer with a couple extra commands. Please post any errors, thanks!